# Different invoice name for different customer group (OC.3.0.3.1)

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I have a question. I have 2 different customer group.

And i want different invoice title. Example:

Customer group1: Invoice

Customer group2: Pre-Invoice

Oc 3.0.3.1 Thanks for help. Im very beginner.

Comment: where you need to improve that ? admin invoice or customer invoice ? otherwise you can upload with screen shot properly because i understand easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this step by step

**Changes : 1**

File Path : `admin\controller\sale\order.php`

Find

```
'voucher'          => $voucher_data,
```

After ADD Below Code

```
'customer_group'   => $order_info['customer_group_id'],
```

**Changes : 2**

File Path : `admin\view\template\sale\order_invoice.twig`

Find

```
<h1>{{ text_invoice }} #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>
```

Replace Below Code

```
{% if order.customer_group == '2' %}
    <h1>Pre-Invoice #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>Invoice #{{ order.order_id }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]